# Weird Color from Apexcharts Heatmap

Tags: apexcharts

In the [doc](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/heatmap-charts/color-range/), the colorScale respect the color code it set, but for my case, the heatmap is displaying every other colors except the colors I choose.

I seriously do not understand what is going on. This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apexchart-heatmap-rv7rt?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the problem

Comment: Your range for "low" is [-1, 0] and for "medium" is [50, 75] - so there's a gap for values between 0 and 50. (Which then take other colors you haven't specified.) When I change the ranges so "low" is [-1, 1] and "medium" is [2, 75] is seems to color like you'd expect. Could this be it?

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks, it appears is the way i pass my data too. i should be passing an array of objects but instead i pass an array of numbers